# prime numbered currency

Tags: prime-numbers

The unit of currency is the Tao(t) the value of each coin is a prime number of Taos. The coin with the smallest value is 2T there are coins of every prime number Value under 50.
Help! I don't under stand if the question means that 1coin equals 2T.
Some pointers in the right direction would be very helpful
Thanks

Comment: Please add more information regarding the question, i.e. a link to the question, some more information about the question (like from which book is it)

Answer (score 1):

The T after the number 2 isn't a variable in this case - it's the unit. Is that what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

It means there are coins of $2,3,5,7,\dots 47$ Taos. You are presumably expected to do some computation using this information.